# Can endemic life linked to a specific weather spawn when it's "Unknown" on the map?

Tags: achievements, monster-hunter-world, monster-hunter-world-iceborne

Currently trying to find a **Wintermoon Nettle** for the achievement, and this critter can only spawn during night time under clear weather. When going into an Expedition, you can usually see the weather (clear, blizzard, sandstorm, etc.), however if an Elder Dragon is present, then the weather is marked as "unknown" on the map. My question is: if I go into the area anyway and see that it *looks clear* in that zone, is it possible that the rare endemic life actually spawned?

Put in another way: has anyone ever seen a Wintermoon Nettle while Velkhana was present on the map?